# Where does Saul's head come from at 0:12?

Tags: part-identification

I'd like to build the same figure but I am unable to locate the head.

[image]

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UajSKjQUDPE

Comment: Welcome! Could you perhaps snap a screenshot of the frame in the video where the head appears, and then attach it to your post? This will save us from having to watch the video, and will help others in the future, should the video in question disappear from YouTube. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[Minifig, Head Dual Sided Brown Eyebrows, Black Eyes with Pupils, Wrinkles, Smile / Determined Pattern (SW Han Solo) - Stud Recessed](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1044#T=C)